# R: Graphical layout parameters not working with mosaic{vcd}

Tags: r, graphics

I want to place to mosaic plots on two adjacent panels. Normally this is a very simple thing to do with `par()`. For example, the following code works perfectly:

```
par(fig=c(0,.55,0,1))
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
par(fig=c(.45,1,0,1), new=T)
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
```

But the code below first produces the first plot, and then simply replaces that by the second:

```
library(vcd)
par(fig=c(0,.55,0,1))
mosaic(~ cut(rnorm(100), breaks=2) + cut(rnorm(100), breaks=3))
par(fig=c(.45,1,0,1), new=T)
mosaic(~ cut(rnorm(100), breaks=2) + cut(rnorm(100), breaks=3))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `mosaic` uses `grid` graphics for plotting and does not use `base` `graphics` which respond to setting `par` parameters. Check out `?gpar` to get started and also `grid.layout`.